# Xdebug with XAMPP in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, xdebug

System Configuration

**Ubuntu 14.04**

**Xampp v 5.6.3**

installed **php5-dev** after xampp on

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

now want to install [`Xdebug`](http://xdebug.org/docs/install) wihin xampp and I tried available 3 method but nothing is working out , please see the whole process.

#### 1)Ubuntu software package

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug
```

command exceuted successfully but no such file in .usr/lib/php5/...

uninstalled

#### 2)Tailored Installation Instructions

downloaded **xdebug.tar.gz** after checking with [wizard](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php)

```
 ice@cold:~/Downloads/xdebug-2.2.6$ /usr/bin/phpize5
```

> /usr/bin/phpize5 Cannot find config.m4.
>   Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize5' in the top level source directory of the module

also tried with `phpize`, `/opt/lampp/bin/phpize` but not working out

#### 3)PECL Installation

before that let me check with `pecl help version`

> PEAR Version: 1.9.4
>   PHP Version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 
>   Zend Engine Version: 2.5.0
>   Running on: Linux ice-cold 3.13.0-39-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 28 13:30:27 UTC 2014 x86_64

```
pecl install xdebug

...
...
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/xdebug-2.2.6
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "zend_extension=xdebug.so" to php.ini
```

executed completely

I can see the file

**644 /usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so**

added below line in /opt/lampp/etc/*php.ini*

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so"
```

restart lampp

but still xdebug icon is missing [image: screenshot]

Please tell me what is wrong

Comment: out of curiosity, why is it that you cannot install php and mysql?

Comment: because xampp is far easy ..all things together

Comment: @diEcho Did you restart the service? Also xampp comes along with xdebug by default but its commented in `php.ini` make sure enable it.

Comment: @RahilWazir how to do this by `php.ini` I havn't seen any entry for xdebug in latest xamppp

Comment: Wow, seriously? 23K rep and you don't know by now that we don't add "SOLVED" to the title? Either delete the question or post the answer and accept it.

Comment: I really dont know this fashion. I was stopping myself to answer because as soon as I write the whole question and I got the answer within 10 minutes. so it can be considered as self question and answer. I want to avoid that.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a self-answer. In fact they're usually encouraged.

Comment: I was banging my head since 3 hours and when finally write up to SO and try one last time . it worked. I fee so excited. Stack overflow itself works like charm for me.

Comment: but giving answer within 10 minutes looks like I have the solution and I want to show the problem first and answer myself. Isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

edited in */opt/lmapp/etc/php.ini* assigned the location of **xdebug.so** to  *zend_extension*

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so"
```

Replace with

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
```

and restart lampp and Xdebug is installed.

[image: screenshot]

AS I was not doing this before because [Xdebug Docs](http://xdebug.org/docs/install) itself warn not to do this

> **Note:** You should ignore any prompts to add "extension=xdebug.so" to php.ini — this will cause problems.

Comment: Bro, I have the same problem I need your help... PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.6.20-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
Zend Engine Version: 2.6.0... I'm not using xampp... I've installed xdebug 2.4 already using PECL like you did... I've tried your answer but no success.

Comment: what is your `xdebug` location? try in terminal with `whereis xdebug`

Comment: I've solved my problem, I was using a different version of `phpize` (5.5.9) obviously it will not work with PHP 5.6.x... so I've downloaded a higher version of `php5-dev` package.

Answer (score 11):

xdebug is located under xampp folder in

> /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so

on ubuntu 14.04 just search for it in /opt/lampp and copy the full path to it and then open php.ini and replace

> ;zend_extension=opcache.so

with

> zend_extension="/path/xdebug.so"

in my case

> zend_extension="/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so"

Comment: this was exactly what was fixing my issue

Answer (score 0):

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
```

Replace with

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="20160603/xdebug.so"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have installed it by:

```
sudo apt install php-pear

sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net

sudo apt install php7.2-dev

sudo pecl install xdebug
```

Read the last part of the output, follow, and add the corresponding zend_extension=... line to your php.ini file. Restart php-fpm (or Apache if you have it as an Apache module), and you'll have XDebug!

In my case:

open `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini`

configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so" to php.ini

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Just type the command `sudo pecl install xdebug`
OR
Install it with source code

```
git clone -b xdebug_2_4 --single-branch https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/
```

OR

```
wget https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/archive/XDEBUG_2_4_0.zip xdebug.zip && unzip xdebug.zip
cd xdebug
sudo chmod +x ./rebuild.sh && ./rebuild.sh
./configure <CONFIG>
make && sudo make install
```